# An infinitely-many-variable formal power series ring ${\Bbb F}_p[[X_1,\ldots]]$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, galois-representations, nonnoetherian

We shall define a infinitely-many-variable formal power series ring ${\Bbb F}_p[[X_1,\ldots]]$ as follows$\colon$

${\Bbb F}_p[[X_1,\ldots]]\colon= \underset{n \geq 1}{\varprojlim}\, {\Bbb F}_p[[X_1,\ldots,X_n]]$.

${\Bbb F}_p[[X_1,\ldots]]$ should be a coherent non-noetherian ring which has not been known yet. To prove its coherence, everything boils down to showing the following fact$\colon$

Let us define $A_{n} \colon= {\Bbb F}_p[[X_1,\ldots,X_{n}]]$, $A_{\infty} \colon= {\Bbb F}_p[[X_1,\ldots]]$ and denote by $F_{\infty}$ the fractional field of $A_{\infty}$. Because each $A_n$ is metrizable, the inverse limit $A_{\infty} \colon= \underset{n \geq 1}{\varprojlim}\,A_n$ is also metrizable. So we shall denote by $d$ the metric on $A_{\infty}$.

We fix an arbitrary positive integer $m$ and consider the vector space

$V \colon= F_{\infty}^{\oplus m}$

over $F_{\infty}$. We put $O \colon= (0,\ldots,0)$ which is the origin of $V$. The lattice of $V$ is defined as

$L \colon= A_{\infty}^{\oplus m}$.

The above meric $d$ on $A_{\infty}$ is inherited on $L$ as well.

Now, let us choose $(m-1)$ vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_{m-1} \in V$ such that $v_1,\ldots,v_{m-1}$ are linearly independent over $F_{\infty}$.

For $c_1,\ldots,c_{m-1} \in F_{\infty}$, we set

$v(c_1,\ldots,c_{m-1}) \colon= c_1v_1 + \ldots + c_{m-1}v_{m-1}$.

Suppose that the following two conditions are satisfied$\colon$

1. $c_1 \notin A_{\infty}$.
2. $v(c_1,\ldots,c_{m-1})=(a_1,\ldots,a_m) \in L$ such that ${\mathrm{GCD}}(a_1,...,a_m) = 1$.

### Q. under these two conditions, is there a constant $C > 0$ such that the following inequalty holds?$\colon$

$d(O, v(c_1,\ldots,c_{m-1})) > C$.

Comment: Please explain what metric you are using, first on $A_\infty$, and then on $L$ and $V$.

Comment: A metric space X is called inverse limit of the system (ϕ_{m,n}, X n ) if its underlying space consists of all sequences x_n ∈X_n such that ϕ_{m,n} (x_m) = x_n for all m ≥ n and for any two such sequences (x_n) and (y_n) the distance is defined by d((x_n), (y_n)) = lim_{n→∞} d(x_n,y_n). For each x_n, y_n ∈ F_p[[X_1,...,X_n]] we set d(x_n,y_n):= d(0,x_n - y_n) = c^{v(x_n-y_n)}, where 0<c<1 and v(a) is the maximal integer s.t. a∈(X_1,...,X_n)^{v(a)}.

Comment: I only endow the induced metric on L, but not on V. On L, for an element v=(a_1,...,a_m) ∈ L, we set d(O,v) := \sqrt{(d(0,a_1)^2 + ... + d(0,a_m)^2}, where d(0,a_i) is the distance between 0 and a_i in A_∞. As I stated, v(c_1,...,c_{m-1}) ∈ L. So my question makes sense.

Comment: Is ​ "each $A_n$ is metrizable" ​ in the sense that _every_ set is metrizable, since the discrete metric works? $\hspace{.36 in}$

Comment: Yes. I think so. But in principle, each A_n is equipped with m-adic topology. So if an element a has the leading monomial of degree e, d(0,a)= c^e with 0 < c < 1 is the fixed constant.